# What's the difference between Control.Select() and Control.Focus()?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, behavior

In WinForms, to set focus to a specific control, I always seem to wind up calling `Control.Select()` **and** `Control.Focus()` to get it to work.

What is the difference, and is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the Select method or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate method for forms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx

Comment: I don't think this is a good enough answer.  I read that and understand that.  I wrote a custom control.  I don't know when it's appropriate for me to use Select vs Focus in my custom control, however.  Is it an always thing?  Is there some set of criteria?  what are the implications of one versus the other, both actual and semantic?

Comment: I suspect most people will have read MSDN before typing this question into Google. Simply repeating it here verbatum is not very helpful.

Answer (score 44):

Focus() is the low level function that actually sets the focus.

Select() is a higer-level method. It first looks iteratively upward in the control's parent hierarchy until it finds a container control. Then it sets that container's ActiveControl property (to the called control). The logic in those methods is not straightforward however, and there is special handling for UserControl containers.

Answer (score 6):

For an example of how they are different, if you are trying to set a control for a Forms App to default focus to when you open it, only Select() will work when called in the constructor after InitializeComponent().  Focus() will not.

Comment: I can see this, what possibly could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to this thread I found that when writing a user control that moved other controls from one form to another (newly created form).  The original form could no longer select the control but using focus allowed it to do so.  I think this emphasises the answers about the levels these methods work at.  But it also means it is not simple enough to say use Select at the higher level since select no longer worked as expected on the orginal form (not that it should being I placed it into a different form - I accept that)

Answer (score 2):

Focus(), in some situations, can cause a window owning the control to gain focus if it didn't have focus. Select() does not cause a focus grab by the window.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience I wrote a user control inheriting the Windows ComboBox. I had to write code to override the `OnEnter` event and I had a statement in there saying

```
If Me.Focused Then ... Else ...
```

However, unfortunately it returned the unexpected result. If I called `MyCustomerComboControl.Select` (in either Load, Shown or Activated events) it called the `OnEnter` method but failed to register it had the focus (i.e. Focused was False) but if I called Focus it worked. Furthermore `Select` worked if the form was open i.e. if I selected another control then re-selected the original control all was fine. So in any other circumstances other than my scenario, use `Select` because it says so above.