# C# What is the difference between Control.Focus() and Control.Select()

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Control.Select() and Control.Focus()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802722/whats-the-difference-between-control-select-and-control-focus)

What is the difference between Control.Focus() and Control.Select()

And is it correct to assume that the form.ActiveControl invokes the Select method of the specified control?

Answer (score 3):

The `Focus()` function actually performs the focussing on the control. The `Select()` function is higher-level, and tells the parent to select through the control's hierarchy.

There is loads of logic in the `Select` function to make custom controls work fully with the framework.

If all you want to do is literally call focus on the element, there is no advantage on using `Select`... it makes me wonder why `Focus` isn't kept as a private/protected function.

Comment: So, Select() tells the parent to set the ActiveControl to the control where Select() is invoked?